# Is it possible to make a selectable drop down menu using data from an XML file?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to create a directory for an address book, and I was wondering if it would be possible to create a selectable drop down menu that would pull the contact data from an XML file. The ideal way I would want it is to have all of the names of the contacts in the drop down menu, and when one is selected the rest of the information would pop up above the drop down, such as Address, Phone Number, and Email.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a server-side language such as PHP to extract the data from the XML and insert it into the HTML document, or use AJAX to pull the XML file to the client then use JavaScript to process it and insert it into the DOM.

There should be libraries/frameworks/plugins/whatever available to parse XML using whatever language you need, if you know how to insert stuff into the HTML document (in the case of PHP) or into the DOM (in the case of JavaScript), you can do this easy.

Comment: Oh okay, but there would be no way to do this without a server side language and just with Javascript? In my class that this project is assigned we have yet to get to server side languages and I don't want to jump the gun. I was just trying to do something a little different than everyone else.

Comment: Do you know about how web servers work yet? Or are you developing your sites purely on your computer and running them using a web browser like Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: Honestly I don't have any clue about web servers or anything, my websites are just saved locally.

Comment: Hmm, that makes it more tricky. You see, Javascript isn't a fully-fledged programming language that's run by the OS. Because you're (usually) downloading Javascripts from the internet without knowing exactly what you're downloading, they don't have permission to do stuff like access files stored on your computer.

The only thing I can think of is if there's some way to link the XML file into the page, similar to how CSS files are loaded, then Javascript may be able to access it. I've never had a reason to do this though so I have no idea if it's possible.

Comment: Hmmmmmm, well I'll keep searching online to see if I can find anything, or maybe an example of what I'm looking for. If you happen to figure anything out i'd appreciate it if you posted it on here. Thanks

Comment: I'll try to explain a little bit more about why it's not really possible in your situation. In general, the HTML, CSS and Javascript files you're developing are stored on a server, and when you load a webpage, it downloads those files to your web browser. In order to get an XML file into your web browser, you need to specifically ask the server for it, which is done via an "AJAX" (Asynchronous Javascript And XML) call.

While you can "fake" this process with HTML etc by just double clicking a HTML file on your computer to open it up, you can't really fake AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an XSL to the XML using something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>
... actual XML content...
```

If applying the XSL on the XML outputs an HTML page with JavaScript, you can get the actual result.
Outputting JavaScript is a bit of a pain because of character escaping but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have an XML document. Using XSLT you create an XHTML file from your XML and that you can display in your browser (XHTML is HTML that is conform to XML rules).

If that is the case then, yes, you can make links using XSLT. But the data needs to be in your XML source file and not in some database.

There is an article that describes it: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipxslt/index.html